# Initialization before or inside the for loop in Java

Tags: java, for-loop

Please tell me what's the difference of these two snippets of code:

```
int i = 0;
for(i; i < test; i++) {...}
```

and

```
for(int i = 0; i < test; i++) {...}
```

Is there any difference between these ways of initializing the `i`-increment variable? Does it affect anything or not?

Answer (score 5):

Difference is the scope of the variable `i`.

In the first one, `i` is visible outside the for loop and in the second one, it isn't.

Comment: thanks...i had a code actually like "for(int i=0;i<test;i++){system.out.println(i+" ");}" so variable i should have been defined outside the for loop.

Comment: @byank In that case the `i` is considered to be *in* the `for`-loop. `i` would however be out of scope after the `for`-loop's closing brace: `for(int i = 0; i<val;i++){System.out.println("OK: " + i);} System.out.println("FAIL: " + i);`

Answer (score 1):

in case one you can use i variable in out side of the for loop scope.
in case two you cant do so. Only can use in for loop scope.

Answer (score 1):

In both cases, the variable is being defined once (no significant performance or memory issues). The differences come in scope and representation. On the first case `i` will be available outside the scope of the `for` statement.

The first case is useful, for example, if you want to find a the particular index of an element (tough there do exist better alternatives to this approach) or if you want to iterate until a certain condition is met and, then, know which index did your loop stop at.

Answer (score 0):

[The second one is idiomatic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html). The first one is not, and as such violates [the principle of least astonishment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

Only use the second one if you need access to `i` before or after the `for` loop. I see nothing in this code to suggest that is the case, however.

Comment: You mean use the first one...